# Email already exists

Tags: php

Alright so for some reason, Im always getting that email already exists if it doesnt.

```
public function emailExists($mail) {
            $handler = new sql();
            $sql = $handler->connect();

            $sql->real_escape_string($mail);

            $result = $sql->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$mail."'");



            if($result->num_rows != 0) return true;
            else {
                $handler->log_write($mail, "register_fail","NULL");
                return false;
            }
            $sql->close();
            return false;
        }
```

Now here is the check

```
if($user->emailExists() == false) {
        $user->create($name, $pass,  $email, $age, $gender);
            jquery_alert("You have been registered. Thank you for using our services. Enjoy your stay!");
            jquery_reload();
        }
        else {
            jquery_alert("This email already exists");
        }
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `$sql->real_escape_string()` back to the variable. It doesn't modify its argument.

Comment: But you really should learn how to use prepared queries instead of escaping strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass email address as argument in method.

```
if($user->emailExists($email) == false) {
// your code here
}
```

Comment: If this answer is useful please mark this answer as useful or up vote.

Answer (score 0):

In your function your returning default value is false

And Also Pass email address in your method.

Try this solution

```
if($user->emailExists($email) == true) {
    $user->create($name, $pass,  $email, $age, $gender);
        jquery_alert("You have been registered. Thank you for using our services. Enjoy your stay!");
        jquery_reload();
    }
    else {
        jquery_alert("This email already exists");
    }
```